# Vaex join two datasets and filter

Tags: python, dataframe, vaex

I would like to perform 2 operations on vaex dataframes:

1. I have two vaex datasets: vaex_cpc having 159,541,409 observations and vaex_id.info with 117,081,595 observations. They both share a column called "docdb_family_id" and I would like to merge the two based on this column.

I tried to do so with:

```
db_cpc_id = vaex_id.join(vaex_cpc, how='left', on='docdb_family_id',allow_duplication=True)
```

but I ended up with a dataframe of more than 500 Million rows. I think this is due to the "allow_duplication=True" option but if I set it to False then an error appears.
From the help file I see "Allow duplication of rows when the joined column
contains non-unique values" but I did not quite understand what this means. What I would like to end up with at the end is a vaex dataframe having the number of rows of the vaex dataframe with the highest number of rows (159,541,409 in my case).

EDIT: should I perform maybe an inner join instead of a left one?

2. I applied a filtering on the same database but when I type head() on the filtered dataset it takes a lot to load (while in the original joined datafreme it takes a second only). The filtering command is:

```
db_cpc_id['cpc_first_letter'] = db_cpc_id['cpc_class_symbol'].str.get(0)
db_cpc_id_green=db_cpc_id.filter(db_cpc_id.cpc_first_letter == 'Y')
```

Any help on the two is well appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

About the join.. i find the error message pretty clear: the duplicates means you have non-unique (or duplicate) entries on the join column.

That means in either or both of the dataframes you have non-unique `docdb_family_id` entries. So vaex will do all combinations which is why the number of columns increases.

So you need to find a way eliminate the duplicates (by either dropping, or by doing some gruopby or whatever) or continue your analysis with the larger joined dataset